# maintain button's position in c#, no matter the resolution of the screen

Tags: c#

i designed a game in c# and finished it... but i tried it on my friend's laptop with different screen size and resolution, all my design was in a total mess!!

if there is a way to keep everything (panels, picturebox,buttons,labels,...) in their positions despite the size and resolution of screen!?!?
really need help, my project's deadline is on Monday :(

Answer (score 2):

Use anchors on your controls:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a windows form application? If so, you can use docking to maintain positions. Also, the positions should stay the same anyway unless the form is not a fixed size.

So use docking or a fixed sized form.

Also, please make sure to specify what type of GUI framework you're using next time. My answer is *incredibly* wrong if you're using something other than windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from docking, another option would be to place all of your objects within a panel, and then center it horizontally and vertically on your `resize event`. e.g.

```
panel1.Left = this.Width/2 + panel1.Width/2;
panel1.Top = this.Height/2 + panel1.Height/2;
```

This will ensure that your applications static contents are always centered, regardless of resolution.

Comment: how about:
if i need to resize everything (panels, labels, picture boxes, buttons, progress bars, ...) and change their location in order to fit in the screen of any size (dimensions) and resolution! the game is always in maximized state.