# Resizing and changing location of all labels,pictureboxes,panels,buttons to fit any screen

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

i am designing a game (using window forms) and need to resize everything (panels, labels, picture boxes, buttons, progress bars, ...) and change their location in order to fit in the screen of any size (dimensions) and resolution! the game is always in maximized state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [maintain button's position in c#, no matter the resolution of the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737113/maintain-buttons-position-in-c-no-matter-the-resolution-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

dock your controls to your form

desolator's comment:
Specically, use a TableLayoutPanel with gui organized in rows and columns. Use Dock.Fill with everything, even with the panels and with the main panel. Notice that panels can be nested and dock.fill ed too

Comment: you should try docking anything in any position other than the sides or fill... it is impossible!

Comment: I dock status panels to the bottom.  Try using controls in panels instead of docking individual controls.

Comment: Using TableLayoutPanel with all things Dock ed is the best solution +1